# MYSQL Query With Select Having Distinct with LIMIT Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently, I have a table as below and I wanted to pull the records with id having the estimated_date which are assigned to least value of update_index value and if the value is null I want to go the value assigned to next update_index,

For example, for record with

- id=73, I want to get the value 2017-06-13 00:00:00
- id=75, I want to get the value 2017-01-01 00:00:00
- id=76, I want to get the value 2018-06-01 00:00:00

**Input Table**

```
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| id | update_index |    estimated_date   |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 73 |       1      | 2017-06-13 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 73 |       2      | 2017-01-13 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 73 |       3      | 2017-05-13 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 73 |       4      |         NULL        |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 75 |       1      | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 75 |       2      |         NULL        |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 75 |       3      | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 76 |       1      |         NULL        |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 76 |       2      | 2018-06-01 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
```

**Output Table**

```
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| id | update_index |    estimated_date   |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 73 |       1      | 2017-06-13 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 75 |       1      | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
| 76 |       2      | 2018-06-01 00:00:00 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+
```

I have tried the below values but I get only one record always, can you please help me with this?

```
SELECT  id,update_index,estimated_date
FROM tablename where estimated_date = (
       SELECT DISTINCT estimated_date
       FROM tablename
        where estimated_date is not null
       ORDER BY id, udpate_index ASC
       LIMIT 1);
 `
```

Comment: Not sure want the logic behide the expected results are here can you elaborate/explain it better?.. at first sight It looks like you only want one record (with `MIN(update_index)` if there are duplicates with in the column `estimated_date`) where there isn't a null value within the column estimated_date within the group id.

Comment: Yes Raymond Correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where t.update_index = (select t2.update_index
                        from tablename t2
                        where t2.id = t.id and t2.estimated_date is not null
                        order by t2.update_index asc
                        limit 1
                       );
```

Comment: It Says Subquery returns more than one row, What should be the issue

Comment: "It Says Subquery returns more than one row, What should be the issue " @Ron the `where t.update_index =` i think should be `where t.update_index IN` instead but most likely you must also use `LIMIT 1` in the subquery.

Comment: @Ron  . . . Because I left out the `limit`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
    select t2.*
    from
    (select id, min(update_index) updated_index 
    from input_table 
    where estimated_date is not null
    group by 1 )t1
    left join input_table t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
    and t1.update_index = t2.update_index
```

Comment: It returns me only 1 Row

Comment: "It returns me only 1 Row" @Ron Thats because the subquery is missing a `GROUP BY id`

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You cant try this:

select t.id, t.update_index, t.estimated_date 
from tablename t
where t.update_index=(select MIN(update_index) from tablename t1 where t1.id=t.id and t1.estimated_date is not null)
group by t.id

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery with `LIMIT` clause :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.update_index = (select t2.update_index
                        from table t2
                        where t2.id = t.id and t2.estimated_date is not null
                        order by t2.estimated_date desc
                        limit 1
                       );
```

However, your sample data more suggest me :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.estimated_date = (select max(t2.estimated_date)
                          from table t2
                          where t2.id = t.id and t2.estimated_date is not null
                         );
```

If you have a ties with `estimated_date` then first approach would work instead.